# Profinet IO device Software

Tags: ethernet

How can I use my computer as a Profinet IO device,

I need to have some read-write parameters for this purpose.

I found this python code: https://github.com/devkid/profinet/tree/master/templates

But when send connection request and receive answer this code does not catch reply so how can I solve this or how can I find the software ?

Comment: You can try and use WireShark to probe the ethernet port and see what messages are sent/received to check if they make sense.

Comment: Yes I checked, I send request getting reply but this communication code does not work

Comment: I am not familiar with profinet, but I'm not sure if this is the best place for this question, it sounds a bit more software-related instead of electronics?